# Why is calculus needed in this problem involving work and units of energy?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Consider this problem:

> Suppose it takes k units of energy to lift a cubic meter of water one meter. About how much energy E will it take to pump dry a circular hole one meter in diameter and 100 meters deep that is filled with water?

Here's how I tried to solve it:

Total volume of water = $\pi r^2h = \pi (\frac{1}{2})^2 100$

Energy required to move this volume of water by $1$ meter $=\pi(\frac{1}{2})^2100k$, and so energy required to move this move this volume of water by $100$ meters $= 100\pi(\frac{1}{2})^2100k = \frac{\pi k10^4}{4}$.

However, the answer given is: $\frac{\pi k10^4}{8}$. Where am I going wrong with my reasoning? Also, this problem was assigned in single variable calculus, under definite integrals. Why is calculus needed here at all?

Comment: You don't have to lift every cup of water out by the whole 100m, unless you want to launch it into the sky :) The top level of the water only needs to be lifted a small amount.

Comment: The amount of work that needs to be done on a given cross section of water depends on the depth of the water, hence calculus.

Comment: Aha, I see now! Your comment gave me a good chuckle, thanks! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to lift every cup of water out by the whole $100$m.  If a given horizontal cross-section of water is a depth $d$ meters, you need to move that cross-section only $d$ meters, not $100$m.  So to find the whole amount of work done you need to add up the work done for each thin cross-section, which depends on the depth; and you can do that with an appropriate integral.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since everything's linear, and since the cross-section $A=\pi r^2$ is constant, consider a vertical element $dh$ near the top, which needn't move hardly at all, so $dE=0kAdh=0$. There's a "complementary" $dh$ element near the bottom that needs to move all $100m$, for which $dE=100kAdh$. Then the total for those two elements is $dE=(0+100)kAdh$.

Moving down a little from the top, say $z$ meters, and up a little from the bottom, you can do the same thing for two more $dh$ elements. And you can see that total in parentheses will just be $((0+z)+(100-z))=(100)$ same as before. And on and on for the whole thing.

So it's basically just the average, *i.e.,* your "top"+"bottom" elements get exhausted at $50m$, whereby the answer's $50Ak$ rather than $100Ak$. And you're right -- the problem can be solved without calculus.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually an overstatement to say that something *needs* Calculus, so even though you have some good answers, I'm going to solve the problem without using Calculus at all.  Your solution was that the total volume of water is $ 25 \pi $ cubic metres, and this is raised $ 100 $ metres, so the total energy required is the product of these numbers and $ k $.  As Jair Taylor's answer pointed out, this is flawed because not all of the water is raised the full height of $ 100 $ metres.  But as John Forkosh's answer pointed out, because the cross sections are all the same, everything is linear.  So we can just say that the *average* height the water is raised is $ 50 $ metres.  Multiply $ 25 \pi $, $ 50 $, and $ k $, and you get the correct answer, $ 1250 \pi k $ units of energy.  (If the cross sections had different areas, say because the hole were shaped like a cone or a paraboloid, which are typical textbook problems, then it would be harder to avoid Caclulus.  Indeed, for the paraboloid, I wouldn't know how to do it without Calculus.)